# how to view log files for printing made by different users on LAN

Tags: windows-server-2003, log-files, user-management, printer

I have a windows 2003 server and have attached a printer to this server. 
This printer is installed on the server and shared to all computers on the local area network.
I want to check to see which users have print jobs and no. of prints, details, etc.
I think there is a facility to see the details but I don't know where it is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a program called PaperCut print logger for this.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The server should log this in the System event log. You can view this using event viewer, or you could put together a script that periodically scans the event log and summarises the relevant info. For example, on one of my print servers I see this event logged:

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   Print
Event Category: None
Event ID:   10
Date:       16/03/2012
Time:       11:35:46
User:       DOMAIN\username
Computer:   PRINTSERVER
Description:
Document <number>, <job name> owned by <username> was printed on
<printer> via port <port name>. Size in bytes: <size>; pages printed: <pages>

For more information, see Help and Support Center at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

The description always follows this same pattern, and the values between brackets are:

- **number** - this seems to increase with each job, it's probably not terribly useful.
- **job name** - Windows programs send a print job name when they print something. For example, a Word doc would send the filename as the job name.
- **username** - the AD username of the person who generated the print job.
- **printer** - the name of the printer.
- **port name** - the port used by the printer on the server. For a normal IP printer this will be something like "IP_172.16.100.50".
- **size** - how big the job was.
- **pages** - how many pages were printed.